# Why the file size exceed after moving ember 1.11.3 and htmlbars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

Recently, I've moved Ember Version 1.11.3. After moving this version, we could see in my file size got increased much.

I didn't use the ember-cli. Using Grunt (0.4.5).

I could see that "HTMLBars: is the reason for the increase in file size of templates. But I just want to know is there any reason to decease my file size?

Please help me out from this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 7SP1 and up you have to run command line with elevated rights otherwise grunt/npm/bower can't create shortcuts and have to copy everything multiple times.